# Holomorphic function zeros on the circle

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm learning to use some methods of complex analysis, solving some problems.
Could you give me a hint to solve the following problem?
$f$ is holomorphic in $D^2=\{z: |z|<1\}$ and continious in $\partial D^2\cup D^2$. Also, there is an open subset $U$ of $\partial D^2$ such as $f|_U=0.$ I am to prove $f|_U=0$.

Unfortunately, I have a lack of techniques, but I think somethin like maximum modulus principle would be useful. Perhaps there is some general result?

Comment: A misprint, of course (there should be $D^2$)
I know that each zero is isolated. And...probably nothing more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The maximum modulus principle is indeed useful to prove that under the assumptions (including $U \neq \varnothing$), you have $f \equiv 0$.

An open subset $U$ of the boundary contains the image of an interval $[a, a + 2\pi/n]$ under $t \mapsto e^{it}$, and with $\zeta = e^{2\pi i/n}$, consider

$$g(z) = \prod_{k=0}^{n-1} f(z\cdot \zeta^k).$$

$g$ is (easily seen to be) holomorphic in the unit disk, and continuous on the boundary. Its boundary values are, by construction, very simple.

---

An alternative way to prove it:

Since $f$ is continuous on $D^2 \cup \partial D^2$, it is the Cauchy integral of its boundary values,

$$f(z) = C_f(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\lvert \zeta\rvert = 1} \frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta - z}\, d\zeta.$$

Since $f$ vanishes on $U$ (which we may assume relatively open in $\partial D^2$), the Cauchy integral defines a holomorphic function on $D^2 \cup U \cup \left(\mathbb{C}\setminus \overline{D^2}\right)$ that vanishes identically on a non-discrete set (namely $U$).

Comment: Daniel, I've noticed that you have been a consistent contributor to math.stackexchange.com for the past three weeks and your answers have always been excellent! I'd like to let you know (but you've probably realised this already) that your contributions are greatly appreciated by, I'm sure, everyone who has observed them. We need more knowledgeable and intelligent people like you on math.stackexchange.com ; I've up-voted answers of yours whenever I've read them. Thank you very much for your answers!

Comment: @AmiteshDatta amen to this.