# Show that $f(z)=0$ for all $z$, where $f$ is an analytic function on the closed unit disc with additional conditions.

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $D$ denote the open ball of unit radius about origin in the complex plane $\Bbb C$.
>
> Let $f$ be a continuous complex-valued function on its closure $D$ which is analytic on $D$. If $f(e^{it}) = 0$ for $0 < t  <\frac{\pi}{2}$ , show that $f(z) = 0 $ for all $z$.

Here is what I tried:

$f$ is analytic on $D$. If I can find a sequence $(z_n)_n$ in $D$ such that $f(z_n)=0\forall n$ and additionally $(z_n)_n$ has a limit point in $D$ then we are done.

I think $f(e^{it}) = 0$  may help finding one sequence but I am not sure.

Will you kindly help?

Comment: Is there a basic property of analytic functions that this exercise might have been intended to illustrate?  I'm not clear how finding a sequence in $D$, the open unit ball centered on the origin, with a limit point in $D$ will allow you to say "we are done".  After all the sequence $\{1/n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ has a limit point in $D$.

Comment: Look at the Cauchy integral of $f$. If you look sharp, you will see that it defines a holomorphic function on a larger connected open set than just the unit disk.

Comment: @hardmath: If the set of zeroes of an analytic function on a connected domain has an accumulation point, the function is zero.

Comment: @Hurkyl. We are not assuming $f$ is analytic on $\ bar D.$... Analytic on $D$, continuous on $\bar D$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I guess cauchy integral is not meant like cauchy sum as in [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/484286), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3801772) or [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326197) but like [4](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3239717), [5](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/735583), [6](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4131469), [7](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3167782/int-0-1-frac1w-z-dw), [8](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/443406/holomorphic-function-zeros-on-the-circle),

Comment: @DanielFischer  [9](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/454860) or [10](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3915151)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let $\omega \ne 1$ be a 5-th root of unity ($\omega^5 = 1$) and define
$$
  g(z) = f(z)f(\omega z)f(\omega^2 z)f(\omega^3 z)f(\omega^4 z) \, .
$$
$g$ is analytic in the unit disk $\Bbb D$ and continuous on it closure because $f$ is.

For every $z \in \partial \Bbb D$, at last one of the points
$z, \omega, z, \omega^2 z, \omega^3 z, \omega^4 z$ has an argument 
between $0$ and $\pi/2$, so that $g(z) = 0$ on the boundary of 
the unit disk.

Now apply the maximum principle.

In the same way one can show that $f$ is identically zero if $f(z)=0$
on *any* segment of the unit circle.

Another option would be to use the [Schwarz reflection principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_reflection_principle) (which is
a more advanced topic however). It implies that $f$ can be continued
analytically to a larger domain containing the arc $\{ e^{it} \mid
0 < t < \pi /2 \}$ in its interior. Then the identity theorem can
be applied.