# Cauchy integral of $\frac{1}{z}$ over closed curve

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

> Let $\gamma: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a closed curve with $0 \notin \gamma([a,b]).$ Compute the Cauchy integral of $f(z):=\frac{1}{z}$ with regards to $\gamma$.

I have to compute

$$\begin{align}
F(z)=\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int _{\gamma}\frac{f(w)}{w-z}dw=\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int _{\gamma}\frac{1}{w^2-wz}dw
\end{align}$$

but as the curve is arbitrary I don't know how to go on. Can you guys help me?

Comment: Why do you say you have to compute *that* integral? It doesn't look correct...And then: distinguish between closed curves enclosing zero and those that don't. And none going on zero, otherwise things go awry.

Comment: In the lecture we defined the Cauchy integral of a function $f$ as $F(z)=\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int _{\gamma}\frac{f(w)}{w-z}dw$. And how do I distinguish between these two types of curves? Don't I need a parametrization of them?

Comment: I think you're mixing stuff here, or else I'm missing something. What you say is an important Cauchy Theorem for analytic functions on a curve and its interior: to find the function's values by means of integral. Yet you asked for the integral of a specific function: very different !

Comment: I just looked it up in the script again. We just defined $F(z)$ to be the Cauchy integral.

Comment: Presumably we want $\gamma$ to be a piecewise smooth curve (or at least a rectifiable curve), and the integral will need to be phrased in terms of the winding number of $\gamma$ around $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We assume that $z \not \in \gamma ([a,b])$, otherwise the integral is not defined.
We can then calculate $\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma} \frac{1}{w} \frac{1}{w-z} \, dz$ by the residue formula:

- If $z = 0$ then $\frac{1}{w} \frac{1}{w-z} = \frac{1}{w^2}$ has residue zero.
- If $z \neq 0$ and both $z$ and $0$ are inside the interior of $\gamma$, then
  $\frac{1}{w}\frac{1}{w-z}$ has two simple poles, with residue $\frac{1}{0-z}$ for the pole at 0 and $\frac{1}{z}$ for the pole at $z$,
  thus in total we get residue zero. Thus if only one of $0$ or $z$ is in the interior of $\gamma$, then we get respectively the residues $\frac{1}{-z}$ and $\frac{1}{z}$.
  If both $0$ and $z$ are outside of $\gamma$ then the integral is zero.

Answer (score 0):

If, as you say, you're not supposed to use the Cauchy theorem, then I guess you're supposed to use the parametrization of the curve.

For a given $\gamma: [a,b] \ni t \mapsto \gamma(t) \in \mathbb C$:
$$ F_\gamma(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma \frac{1}{w(w-z)} dw = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_a^b \frac{1}{\gamma(t) \big(\gamma(t)-z\big)}\frac{d\gamma(t)}{dt}dt$$
You cannot actualy calculate this integral unless you knwo what the curve is, but given a parametrization, it can be done for any curve, closed or not.