# a confuse about jump theorem and uniqueness of analytic function?

Tags: complex-analysis

> Jump Theorem for Cauchy Integrals:Suppose that $r$ is
> a smooth curve that passes through $z_0$, and $f(z)$ is a continuous function
> on $r$ that is analytic at $z_0$. Let $U$ be a small disk containing $z_0$ such that
> $f(z)$ is analytic on $U$ and such that $r$ divides $U$ into the two components $U_+$
> and $U_-$ as above. $F(ζ)$ is cauchy integral of $f(z)$ over $r$. Then there are analytic functions $F_+(ζ)$ and $F_-(ζ)$ on $U$
> satisfying :$F(ζ)$=$F_+(ζ)$ as $ζ∈U_+$,$F(ζ)$=$F_-(ζ)$ as $ζ∈U_-$, and $F_-(ζ)$=$F_+(ζ)+f(ζ)$as $ζ∈U$.
> $F_-(ζ)$=$\frac{1}{2πi} \int_{r+} \frac{f(z)}{z-ζ}dz +\frac{1}{2πi} \int_{r-r_0} \frac{f(z)}{z-ζ}dz$
> $F_+(ζ)$=$\frac{1}{2πi} \int_{r-} \frac{f(z)}{z-ζ}dz +\frac{1}{2πi} \int_{r-r_0} \frac{f(z)}{z-ζ}dz$.
> $r-$  is left boundary of $U_-$,$r+$  is right boundary of $U_+$,$r_0$ is the common boundary of $U_+$ and $U_-$.

> uniqueness of analytic function:if $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ is analytic function on $D$,and $f(z)=g(z)$ on a set which has a limitpoint,then $f(z)=g(z)$ on $D$.

Confuse:since $F(ζ)=F_+(ζ)$ as $ζ∈U_+$, $F(ζ)$ and $F_+(ζ)$ are analytic on ${U-r_0}$,so$F(ζ)=F_+(ζ)$ as $ζ∈\{U-r_0\}$,then $F_+(ζ)=F_-(ζ)$ as$ζ∈U_-$,this is contraduction with euqality $F_-(ζ)$=$F_+(ζ)+f(ζ)$as $ζ∈U$.

Comment: I known,i ignore the $U-r_0$ is not domain.