# Bounded holomorphic function over unit disk uniquely determines a bounded function on the boundary by taking the limit

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

Now given $f \in H^\infty(D)$, I want to show by functional analysis that there exists $f^\star \in L^\infty(\partial D)$ such that $f$ is determined by $f^\star$ via cauchy integral over the boundary of the disk and that $\lim_{r \to 1^{-}}f(re^{i\theta}) =f^\star(e^{i\theta})$ for a.e. $\theta \in (-\pi, \pi]$.

My progress so far:

Given $|z| < r < 1$, we have by cauchy integral formula,

$$f(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial D(0,r)} \frac{f(w)}{w-z}dw = \frac{1}{2\pi }\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(re^{i \theta})\frac{re^{i \theta}}{re^{i \theta}-z}dz$$

Consider $f_r \in L^\infty(\partial D)$ such that $f_r(\theta) = f(re^{i \theta})$ and let $f^\star \in L^\infty(\partial D)$ denote the weak-$\star$ limit of $f_r$ as $r$ goes $1$ with respect to functions in $L^1(\partial D)$.  Therefore, $$ f(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial D} \frac{f^\star(w)}{w-z}dw$$

Thus it remains to show that the limit is $f^\star$ and then I'm got stuck.
My professor hints that I can use Lebesgue differentiation theorem to derive that

$$f(re^{i\theta}) = \int_{-\pi}^\pi f^\star(e^{i\theta}) \frac{e^{i \tau}}{e^{i \tau}-re^{i\theta}} d\tau$$

which thus converges to $f^\star(e^{i\theta})$ as $r \to 1$, but I'm not really sure how to get this step. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

This is known as Fatou’s theorem. In fact, for complex borel measure $\mu$ which support on $\mathbb{T}$. The Poisson integral of $\mu$, defined by $P[d\mu](z)=\int_{\mathbb{T}}\frac{1-|z|^2}{|1-\overline{z}\zeta|}dm(\zeta)$, has radical limit almost every where(respect to Lebesgue measure $dm=\frac{d\theta}{2\pi}$), which is $\frac{d\mu}{dm}$. Then for $L^{p}(\mathbb{T})$ case, $1\leq p\leq +\infty$, $f^*dm$ defined a complex measure on $\mathbb{T}$. Because $f$ is holomorphic, the Fourier coefficients of $f_r$ supports on $\mathbb{Z_{\geq 0}}$. Also note that “Take Fourier coefficients” is w*-continuous, this shows the Fourier coefficients of $f^*$ also supports on $\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$. This deduce the Poisson integral and Cauchy integral of $f^*$ are coincide.

For the proof of Fatou’s theorem, see Hoffman’s *Banach Spaces of Analytic Functions* page 34, which is use the method of “good kernel”. For another proof using Littilewood maximal function, see Rudin’s *Function Theory in Polydiscs* theorem 2.3.1 page 24.